# Backing Up to SD Card Using TWRP and No Display

Tags: adb, backup, external-sd, twrp, nandroid

I have a device with a broken display. The only way I can initiate commands on it are with the power, volume, and home buttons, and with `adb`. I've installed TWRP on it, and I'm able to boot into it. I'm trying to back up everything on the device I can to a 32GB SD card in the device's SD card slot. But when I keep getting the following result:

```
~ # twrp backup SDBOM

Setting backup options:
System
Data
Boot
Compression is on
Digest Generation is off
Updating partition details...
...done
 * Total number of partitions to back up: 3
 * Total size of all data: 7976MB
 * Available space: 496MB
Not enough free space on storage.
Backup Failed
Done processing script file
```

The SD Card has *more* than enough space for the backup (several times over, in fact), so clearly TWRP is attempting to save the backup to the device's internal storage. I've heard tell (I'm afraid I can't find the link right now) that `twrp backup` in the command line saves to the Storage last selected in the graphical version, but since my device's display is broken I can't select the SD Card as the storage for the backup.

Since I have no display, I also can't do `adb backup --twrp`, since that requires confirmation on the screen.

Is there any way to select the storage for `twrp backup` fully through the terminal? For example, is there an environment variable I can set, or something I can pass `twrp backup`?

Comment: I was always under the impression the twrp and roms wipe the device unless you installed and used it before the screen stopped working.

Comment: @William Apparently not! At least not the way I installed it, and on the device (Samsung Galaxy Tab S).

Comment: The recovery partition is completely separated from the system, data, cache, boot etc partitions so flashing a recovery to replace the recovery partition shouldn't interfere with any other partition.. It's recommended that after installing any customizations that you wipe the dalvik cache and cache but i haven't heard of fully wiping the data partition unless flashing an entire ROM ( Firmware ) that'll replace your system, boot,  user data and recovery.